# Map may not zoom so far out

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, zooming, mapkit

Simple question:

Is it possible to do a max zoom-level? e.g.

```
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
```

I don't want to do it static. Think about the max possible zoom-level.
Where should I define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, just implement the delegate method `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:`, I did it like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta < YOUR_VALUE) {
        MKCoordinateRegion initialRegion;
        initialRegion.center = mapView.region.center;
        initialRegion.span.latitudeDelta = YOUR_VALUE;
        initialRegion.span.longitudeDelta = YOUR_VALUE;
        MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:initialRegion];

        [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:animated];
        [mapView regionThatFits:adjustedRegion];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, one of them allows you to define a minimum zoom value and the other one a maximum, usually I try one and if it not then I change if for the other one ;)